# Cannot change datasource for a subreport: no data returned with the new datasource

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a main report with 3 sub reports connected to an SQL database.  I am attempting to change the report to a different ODBC connection.  I used the "set datasource location" to update the ODBC.  The main report works fine, but the sub reports do not return any data.  I have saved the sub reports as a separate report and tried to run them.  They will still not return any data.  If I change the ODBC location back to the original it works fine.  The 2 databases are identical.  It seems like there is something within the sub report that is not updating to the new database.  The main report is hitting the same tables as the sub reports and it is working.

I am running Windows 7 and Crystal XI.

Comment: Main report and subreport data sources are set independently. Did you update all 4 (main report + 3 subs) to the new source? Also, are the subreports filtered according to data from the main report in any way?

Comment: Have you update the data source of sub reports?

Comment: Yes I did update the data source for all of the sub reports.

Comment: I did find the issue, but I do not know how to fix it. In select expert there should be 5 items, say A, B, C, D, E to select from.  "A" is missing from the list.  I double checked the database and the values are there.  All of the other reports I have that do not use "A" works fine.

Comment: Are you talking about the select expert from the main report or subreports? What is the selection formula you're talking about and what are the DB values, exactly? More details, please!

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on each Sub-report and then select "Edit Sub-report" and there change the Data-source Location and save it. Do it for each sub-report.